# JavaScript : How to split string by seperator and convert it into key : value pair

Tags: javascript, string, object, split

I need help to split below given string with double colon as a separator, and want to convert it into key value pair. ( Note : Last item will be separator )

```
var str = "Name::jignesh::Age::34::pageName::home::device::tablet::";
```

OUTPUT required:

```
{
 Name:jignesh,
 Age:34,
 pageName: home,
 device: tablet
}
```

I tried to split it using str.split('::'), which outputs as :

```
Array(9) [ "Name", "jignesh", "Age", "34", "pageName", "home", "device", "tablet", "" ]
```

Can anyone please guide on that.

Thanks,
Jignesh

Comment: Iterate by twos until there's only one item left and set object properties using bracket notation until done. (Noting that there are libraries that'll do this automagically.) But not a bad interview question as a quick sanity check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
const str = "Name::jignesh::Age::34::pageName::home::device::tablet::";

const dictionary = str.split('::').reduce((accumulator, key, i, array) => {
  // in case the current key's index is an 
  // even value AND it is not an empty string
  return i % 2 === 0 && key
    // include the "key: value" pair into the dictionary
    ? {...accumulator, [key]: array[i + 1]}
    // else - continue
    : accumulator;
}, {});

console.log(dictionary);
```

Comment: Thank you @Alexander Lomia, your solution is working fine. Thanks again for your valuable help.